# Resolving php unserialize error at offset in Redis caching

Tags: php, redis

I'm currently using Redis to cache my database results. What I did was to place the db results into an array and serializing the array before adding them as values to my keys in the Redis cache.

```
$res = $this->db->query($qry);
foreach($res->result() as $row) {
  $curArr[] = $row;
}
$this->redis->set($key, serialize($curArr));
```

But, whenever I unserialize the cache, it returns an error in the offset.

```
$cache_result = $this->redis->get($key);
$curArr = unserialize($cache_result);

Message:  unserialize(): Error at offset 8193 of 8701 bytes
```

When I checked the $cache_result, the length of the string is 8702 and the character at 8194 is ';'. The string snippet for that part is 'Test 3\";s:7'. There are also various occurrences of that string snippet in $cache_result but the error just appears in 8193.

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: try to use addslashes() so it will add **/** before undetected charactor

Comment: try  $curArr[] = addslashes($row);  instead only  $curArr[] = $row;

Comment: There was an error when i tried $curArr[] = addslashes($row); since addslashes was expecting a string as parameter. I added it to $this->redis->set($key, addslashes(serialize($curArr))); instead but I'm still getting the unserialize() error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do something like this instead : 

    `$res = $this->db->query($qry); 
    foreach($res->result() as $row) 
    { 
     $curArr[] = $row;

    }
     $this->redis->set($key, json_encode($curArr));`

While retrieving:

> $cache_result = $this->redis->get($key);
>
> $curArr = json_decode($cache_result);